# installing inconsolata on netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: unix, netbeans, ubuntu, fonts, netbeans-6.9

i'm using inconsolata for my monospaced fonts on ubuntu 10.10.

i recently installed netbeans 6.9.1 and was wondering why Inconsolata doesn't appear in the 
editor font list under Tools / Options.

Any instruction how can i use Inconsolata on netbeans 6.9?

Thanks

Comment: On the Windows platform, NetBeans seems to be able to pick up new fonts installed into the OS without any user action on the NetBeans side. :-/ There is a `font.properties` file for NetBeans somewhere, but I was under the impression that it was only used to map logical font names to a different physical font. Maybe you can try mapping `Mono` to that physical font. Also, sometimes a font's physical name is somewhat different than its "common" name. Maybe NB lists it that way. Did you scroll through the list completely looking for a reference to it under a modified name?

Answer (score 1):

seems like netbeans doesn't support opentype fonts.

ttfs will work. get it here from [kevin vanzonneveld](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/install_the_best_coding_font/)